# What happened to Launch?

Tags: dragon-ball-series

Early in the Dragon Ball series, Goku and Krillin rescue a chick named Launch who could switch personalities by sneezing. What happened to her? They don't give any mention about her in Dragon Ball Z or GT, and she seems to have just disappeared in Dragon Ball.

Comment: Actually, she does appear in *Dragon Ball Z* (Vegeta Saga and Kid Buu Saga) and also later in *Yo! Son Goku and His Friends Return!!*

Comment: Really? I guess I may have missed it. Then again, I moreso read Dragon Ball Z then watched it, so she may have popped up as filler at one point that wouldn't normally be in the manga.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

According to the [DragonBall wikia](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Launch) and [TvTropes](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Characters/DragonBallSupportingCast), Akira Toriyama gave a statement saying that  the reason Lunch stopped appearing during Dragon Ball Z was because he simply forgot about her and that her bad state would have caused confusion because of its similarity to the Super Saiyan transformation.

She does appear three times in Dragonball Z's anime - most prominently at the beginning of the Vegeta Saga - although she mainly appears in filler or flashbacks. In the manga she doesn't seem to be there at all.

The original source of the interview seemingly in the March 24th 2013 edition of Mandō Kobayashi.

Comment: poor launch . .